# How can we make unique and restrited fields in collection ( in mongodb stitch )?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

How can we make unique `keys` in `collection` ? any **expressions** or **rules** for it ?

Also i have created a `collection` `users` for user info and there is a field named **role** i want that only admin can update that field value. any suggestion how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

For unique keys please see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

In regards to restricting updating a certain field, that needs to be handled in your application by checking user permissions before sending an operation to your MongoDB database.

If you need to restrict things at the database level as well, please see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/

Comment: I am talking about MongoDB Stitch.

Comment: On their marketing page it says:

"All of MongoDB

Unlike other backend offerings, get the full power and scalability of MongoDB – whether using your existing database or starting from scratch. Retain direct access to the database." so you should be able to do anything MongoDB does with this service. So both indexing and authorization from the core of MongoDB should be available to you. If not, you should speak directly with MongoDB as Stitch is still in beta.

Comment: For Stitch related documentation, refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/

Comment: I know. I have spent much time to reading documentation and have not found any solution for these things. thats why i asked here.